# Unipolar transistor as current amplifier

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, amplifier, common-mode

MOSFET or just FET: Common Source, Common Drain or Common Gate

Can be Unipolar Junction Transistor used as a current amplifier (or just voltage amplifier, because Gate's extremely low current)? If it is, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are getting your terms mixed up a bit. A Unijunction Transistor is a device that acts a switch and cannot be used as a linear amplifier.

[Unijunction Transistor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unijunction_transistor)

The term Unipolar Transistor is very rarely used - I have never heard it in 50 years. That is a name for an FET since it only uses majority carriers.

You can easily use an FET as a current amplifier by using a resistor to convert the input current into a voltage then using the FET to amplify that voltage to a current

To get accuracy from a circuit like this one would usually use a differential stage to cancel the threshold voltage and an opamp with a feedback circuit to control the gain. In this example the gain will vary with the gm of the FET and there will be a standing current that depends upon the threshold voltage of the device.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBDQC8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It is rare however to require an amplifier to output current though - usually the need is to amplify a small voltage (or current) with voltage as the output.

Comment: As voltage amplifier yes, but how to be used as current amplifier since the gate has such high resistance? If I'm not wrong, every configuration of FET has current amplification of 1.

Comment: Oh, by the way, I didn't mean UJT (unijunction transistor) but unipolar transistor.

Comment: Do you actually need a current amplifier?  It is rare to need a current output from an amplifier.  A common requirement is for a current input and voltage output which is easy with FETs.  Bipolar transistors are rarely used as current amplifiers - the input current is usually an inconvenience.

Comment: No, but I am learning about it at the moment. Just, tell me how can it be used as a current amp since it has such high input impedance (for common source which is most commonly used).

Comment: That's what I described in the answer.  Put a resistor between gate and source.  Feed the input current into the gate.  The drain will then have an amplified version of the current.  You can amplify currents from nano amps to Amps depending upon the value of the resistor.

Comment: Although there are many differences between BJT an FET or MOSFET. Which one is more often used a amplifier?

Comment: If you are discussing discrete amplifiers for low to medium frequency I would expect bipolar to be used more than the others.  (MOS)FETs would often be used where there high input impedance can be exploited such as the input stage of a scope front-end followed by BJTs.  A difficulty with FETs is that there threshold voltages vary a lot between units and that makes them tricky to use.  Often these days an opamp would be used and the tricky bits would be hidden by using differential amplifiers within an IC.